# Turning CSV into a dictionary, part of the cells have multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am trying to turn a csv file into a dictionary.
the sctructure is as follows:

key | value1 \n value2 \n
Meaning- on the left cell I have a key, on the right there are values separated by line drops.

The code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))


result = {}
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    item = (row[0].split('\t'))
    print(item)
    key = item[0]
    if key in result:
        # implement your duplicate row handling here
        pass
    result[key] = item[1:]
print(result)
```

but the result I get is like that (part of the dictionary):

'key': ['"value1'], 'value2"': []

How do I make all the contents in a cell in csv appear as a list of values for the single key on the left?

Comment: Your csv needs to wrap the multi-line cells in quotes (`"`) for them to be considered as a single cell that contain `\n`, otherwise the `csv` module won't read it correctly. Also, do `csv.reader(open('test.csv'), delimiter='\t')` if you know your delimiter is a tab. Why use `csv.reader` and not get it to auto-split the columns for you?

Comment: So how should I approach that? add quotes to every line? What about Excel?

Comment: I'm going to demonstrate with commas as delimiters, but `key,"value1\nvalue2"\nkey2,"value3\nvalue4"\n...`. Then see what `row` contains.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot! Didn't know CSV behaved like that.